# Working with Bunifu Framework on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, tabpage, bunifu

I am currently working on a small project that I would like to continue rather than disband because of this issue. However, I've tried many online solutions including the official blog of Bunifu Framework but no success.

My problem is very frustrating because the scrollbar seems to work only on one tabpage. The scrollbar control includes a **BindingContainer** property which allows me to bind the scrollbar to a panel. However, that didn't solved my issue. Is there anything I can possibly do to fix this bug / issue on my own? The developers of Bunifu didn't seem to fix the issue in their recent updates.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide some code that you think is important for someone to answer. This makes it easier to find a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you! :)

Unfortunately, there is no code required to bind the scrollbar to the control.

The code to bind it is basically very simple:
`bunifuVScrollBar.BindingContainer = myPanel;`

Answer (score 1):

If you had 3 tab bunifu pages, then create 3bunifu scrollbars. Then add all scroll bars on first tab page. Then Bind. (hide the scroll bar, by using transparent colour)